# Qt: Prevent taskbar from appearing in fullscreen apps

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a Qt app that is designed to cover the entire screen, hiding the taskbar of the desktop. I achieved this by showing the window with `QWidget::showFullScreen` and it works as desired. However, if I open a dialog box over my app, the desktop taskbar appears with it. How can I keep the taskbar from showing up without making my app's popups full screen?

Example code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}



//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //sometime later, a popup is shown
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, [this]{
        Message msgBox = new MessageBox(message, this);
        msgBox->exec();
    });    
}


//messagebox.cpp
#include "messagebox.h"
#include "ui_messagebox.h"

MessageBox::MessageBox(const QString &message, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MessageBox)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);

    if(parent){
        auto hostRect = parent->geometry();
        this->move(hostRect.center() - this->rect().center());
    }

    ui->label->setText(message);
}
```

The example message box is simply a frameless, modal dialog with a label and an OK/Close button. It appears and works exactly how I would like it to, except that it causes the taskbar of the window manager to appear whenever it is opened. How can I enforce that the taskbar never appears?

App runs on Debian Stretch, Qt Version is 5.11.3

Comment: Hi, same issue here.. did you find a solution ?

Comment: @rok Unfortunately no. For my use case I was able to use openbox as my window manager, which doesn't have a taskbar.